# Evaluating the volume of $n$-ball by using the volume of unit ball?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to proof by **induction** that the volume of a $n$-ball of radius $r$ which denotes as $ V(B_n(r))$ can be calculated using the volume of unit ball  $V(B_n(1))$ by the formula:
$$V(B_n(r)) = r^nV(B_n(1))$$. I do know that we can proof this via multivariate calculus. Many thanks?

Answer (score 1):

We can subdivide $B_n(r)$ into infinitesimally thick disks $B_{n-1}(\sqrt{(r^2-x^2)})$ for $x \in [-r,r]$. Therefore, $V(B_n(r)) = \int_{-r}^r V(B_{n-1}\sqrt{(r^2-x^2)})dx$. Then we can apply induction and change of variables $y=\frac{x}{r}$.